# how to plot svgs inside another svg?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg

[image: Current Output]

```html
let shape = document?.getElementById('path') ;
const random = (min: any, max: any) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
let retArr= [];
   const min_x = shape.getBBox().x;
    const max_x =  shape.getBBox().width + shape.getBBox().x  ;
    const min_y = shape.getBBox().y;
    const max_y =  shape.getBBox().height + shape.getBBox().y;
    
         for(let i =0; i<70; i++){
        const x:any =  random(min_x, max_x);
        const y:any =   random(min_y, max_y);
        retArr.push({x,y});
        }
```

```html
let shape = document?.getElementById('path') ;
let retArr= [];
   const min_x = shape.getBBox().x;
    const max_x =  shape.getBBox().width + shape.getBBox().x  ;
    const min_y = shape.getBBox().y;
    const max_y =  shape.getBBox().height + shape.getBBox().y;
    
         for(let i =0; i<70; i++){
        const x:any =  random(min_x, max_x);
        const y:any =   random(min_y, max_y);
        retArr.push({x,y});
        }
```

I want to insert 70 other svgs into the parent one. All of those should be inside the parent shape. I have tried the above logic but that doesn't seem to work. Many points are falling out of the shape based on the above logic

Comment: There's no markup, please edit the code such that it can be run to demonstrate the problem. You also seem to have included the code twice. We don't need 70 svgs 2 or 3 simplified ones would likely do so we can see what the issue is.

Comment: I have attached an image whoch shows the current output

Comment: Those may be birds or flowers but all the same. You can use an <use> element of a symbot, every time with a random position snd rotation.

Comment: @enxaneta I am using symbol and <use.> element. I am using the co-ordinates returned by the above method to translate the <use> element. But the points are not inside the parent circle. The parent shape can be anything

Comment: instead of translating you can give the <use> an x and y attributes. Also from the image I would think that the symbol have a lot of empty space aroung the bird. You may need to redefine the viewBox of the symbol

Answer (score 1):

In the next example I'm using javascript to create 10 shapes (you can do the same for 70).

For clarity I'm using a simple function. You may want to build an object.

All shapes have a random position and are rotated a random angle. You may also try to use a random size. In this case you may want to recalculate the R constant and it may need to go inside the function.

Please read the comments in the code

```js
const SVG_NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
const SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
const R = 100 - 12.5; //circle's radius - half bird width

function bird() {
  //create a new use element
  let use = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, "use");
  use.setAttributeNS(SVG_XLINK, "xlink:href", "#s");

  //set the width and the height of the use element
  use.setAttribute("width", "21");
  use.setAttribute("height", "21");
  //set the random rotation. The shape is also translated backward half width so that it centers around 0
  let rot = Math.round(Math.random() * 360);
  use.setAttribute("transform", `rotate(${rot}) translate(-12.5 -12.5)`);

  //calculate and set the x and y attributes for the use element
  let a = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;

  //I use this algorithm to avoid to many points in the center of the circle. Please read more about Disk Point Picking

  let r = Math.sqrt(~~(Math.random() * R * R));
  let x = r * Math.cos(a);
  let y = r * Math.sin(a);

  use.setAttribute("x", x);
  use.setAttribute("y", y);

  svg.appendChild(use);
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  bird();
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-100 -100 200 200" width="200" id="svg">
 <circle r="100"/>
 <symbol id="s"  viewBox="-21 -18.5 42 42">
  <path stroke="gold" stroke-width="4" fill="white" 
        d="M-10,-5
           Q0,-30 10,-5
           Q30,0 10,5
           Q0,40 -10,5
           Q-30,0 -10,-5Z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Please read more about [Disk Point Picking](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html)

Comment: What if the outer shape is not circular? The outer shape can be anything

Comment: in this case you may plot it inside a rect the same size as the bounding box of the outer shape and use clipPath to cut the rect with theouter shape. Yet another way would be using [SVGGeometryElement.isPointInFill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/isPointInFill) to check every point